# FastColoredTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Через `NuGet` установил данную библиотеку.

Не могу разобраться, как использовать такую же подсветку синтаксиса как на скриншоте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно самому делать? Или есть, так сказать, "готовый шаблон"? :)

Comment: Проще всего сразу воспользоваться свойством `Language` и задать язык синтаксис которого вы собираетесь подсвечивать.

Comment: @Bulson, то, что надо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

обновление стиля на измененном участке текста:

```
Style GreenStyle = new TextStyle(Brushes.Green, null, FontStyle.Italic);
...
private void fastColoredTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //очистить стиль в измененном блоке текста
    e.ChangedRange.ClearStyle(GreenStyle);

    //подсветка нескольких слов через регулярное выражение
    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(BoldStyle, @"\b(class|struct|enum)\s+(?<range>[\w_]+?)\b");
}
```

Детали как общатся с компонентом можно найти здесь:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/%2FArticles%2F161871%2FFast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting-2